# Pandas: assigning values to a dataframe column based on pivot table values using an if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the Titanic Kaggle data as a means to explore Pandas. I'm trying to figure out how to use an if statement inside of .ix[] (or otherwise) I have a pivot table I'm using to get a lookup value into my main dataframe. Here's a chunk of the pivot table (entitled 'data'):

```
                     Survived       Count      % Female Survived % Male Survived  \
Sex               female male female male                                     
Embarked Pclass                                                               
C        1            42   17     43   42             97.67           40.48   
         2             7    2      7   10            100.00           20.00   
         3            15   10     23   43             65.22           23.26
```

Now I would like to go through each line in the main dataframe to assign its looked up value. No problem looking up the value hardcoded like:

```
df['Chance of Survival'] = data.ix['C']['% Female Survived'].get(1)
97.67
```

However when trying to insert the dynamic portion to include an if statement, things don't work out so great:

```
df['Chance of Survival'] = data.ix[df.Embarked][('% Female Survived' if df.Sex == 'female') | ('% Male Survived' if df.Sex=='male')].get(df.Pclass)
```

So the desired output in my main dataframe would look like this:

```
PersonId    Embarked    Sex    Pclass    Chance of Survival
1           C           female 1         97.67
2           C           male   2         20.00
3           C           male   3         23.26
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What is the dymanic portion? Please refine your example and describe what result you want to achieve. Preferably with code I can copypaste to reproduce your dataframes.

Comment: @firelynx The dynamic portion would be assigning values to a new column in the main dataframe based on line elements on each row in the dataframe; as shwon in the third snippet. The question isn't specific to my dataframe, I just used that as my current problem. I can figure it out from an answer derived from an example dataframe. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer based on what I understand of your problem, please give feedback if it helps or not.

Comment: I can understand where the confusion comes from, I tried to explain more what I was looking for under your answer. I also revised my question to include desired output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it but in case anyone else has a similar problem. Or better yet, if anyone has a nicer way of doing it. :)

```
def getValue(line):
    '''Lookup value in pivot table "data" given the contents of the line passed in from df'''
    value = lambda line: '% Male Survived' if line.Sex == 'male' else '% Female Survived'
    result = data.ix[line.Embarked][value(line)].get(line.Pclass)
    return result

df['Chance of Survival'] = df.apply(getValue, axis=1)
```

So anyone who wants to assign values in the column of one dataframe based on values from another. I used .ix[] to drill down to the value, then .apply() to apply a function across each row (axis=1) finding the line's values just as you would a dataframe. ('line.element'/line['element'])

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to assign values to an existing dataframe and you are currently using DataFrame.ix

The method you probably want is DataFrame.loc which works like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3,4], 'bar':[1,2,3,4]})
df

   bar  foo

0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4

df.loc[1]['foo'] = 4
df

   bar  foo
0   1   1
1   2   4
2   3   3
3   4   4
```

If you want to assign to new columns, you just have to create them first, simply

```
df['newcolumn'] = np.nan
```

Then you can assign it with the code above.

Comment: I'm actually trying to assign values to a new column from values calculated in a pivot table. ie. if row 1 under column 'foo' == 'thing1' AND column 'bar' == 'thing2' then I want to get the calculated value held in the pivot table for where those two meet. In my example this would be 97.67 going to any row in the main dataframe where Sex == 'female', Embarked == 'C', and 'Pclass' == 1  -- Thanks for the attempt!